# an one "no not" to eat

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

> But now I have written unto you not to keep company, if any man that
>   is called a brother be a fornicator, or covetous, or an idolater, or a
>   railer, or a drunkard, or an extortioner; with such an one **no not**
>   to eat.
>   <sub>(1 Corinthians 5: 11)</sub>

Would you please explain to me how **no not** works at the end of this verse?

Comment: For a King James bible verse? Try [here](http://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/5-11.htm); "Don't even eat with such people" or "not even to eat with such a one" or "You must even stop eating with someone like that".

Comment: If the King James bible hadn't been personally approved by God, I suspect that this would be universally acknowledged as some kind of typo.

Comment: @PeterShor "If English was good enough for Jesus Christ, it's the only language I need!" - Marge Schott

Comment: Is it possible it is an error in transcription and should read ***know** not to eat*?

Comment: What do the more recent translations say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Google search on that verse teaches me that the meaning is "Do not eat with such a person". You are quoting the King James Bible, which, although it contributed greatly to the English language, does not always use vocabulary or constructions that are immediately recognizable or easy to identify.

> With such an one no not to eat.

"an" seems strange, I would use "a" in this case.
"such a one" is a person as described in the preceding phrase.
I would read "no not to eat" as

> No, (you are) not to eat (with such a person).

So it becomes something like

> With such a one (= such a person), no, (you are supposed) not to eat.

Comment: Yes, the simple addition of a comma helps a lot.

Comment: I believe "an one" is correct for King James-era pronunciation. It is most certainly incorrect now.

Comment: @PeterShor: 'Not used in my locality' is not 'certainly incorrect'. "To such an one, if such there be, I swear by Heaven's arch above you..." *Pirates of Penzance*

Comment: @Tim: that's from 130 years ago, a third of the way to King James's time. But you're right … there may still be a few dialects that use *"an one"*.